# Outlook does not recognize Mime type- application/json in Html Email campaign

Tags: html, amazon-s3, outlook, mime-types

**Windows has the following information about this MIME type. This page will help you find software needed to open your file. 
MIME Type: application/json
Description: UnKnown
Windows does not recognize this MIME type**

This is the message some of my emails show when opened on outlook. Does it have anything to do with the images in my email being store in Amazon S3 Bucket? If so, where should I possibly pull my images from in email . Also please note that the images are being dynamically pulled via ruby code.

Comment: And what you really expect Outlook should do with your json?

Comment: Exactly - my question here is, is this message occuring because i have my images pulled in from Amazon s3 bucket(where probably the images are stored as xml or json?) Since I am not using any jSon otherwise in my HTML email.